# WDS- Boot image drivers

Tags: windows-server-2003, wds

I have this situation:

> I have Windows Deployment Service in my network. Also I have lots of old and different machines with XP. I have shared directory with tons of drivers in my 2003 server.

What I have achieved:

> I have added XP image to WDS and that image can grab drivers from server's shared directory

For what I'm looking:

> How to prevent boot image to load drivers from server's shared folder if nesssasy??

Comment: Why do you want to prevent drivers from being loaded?

Comment: In my network are tone of old and new network cards and almos each day that number grows. So I don't want to manualy insert them to all boot images. I'm looking for a way to specificate path in each boot image where they can look for a drivers and load them if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to acheive your goal is the [Microsoft Deployment Toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/solutionaccelerators/dd407791.aspx) - MDT. MDT can be used in conjunction with WDS, and can make many things easier with a task based process. You load your drivers into the MDT driver store, and during image deployment, MDT will use PnP calls to install the proper drivers from the driver store, or you can group your drivers and use selection profiles to make sure that only the proper drivers are used. For boot images, you can create a selection profile for just network storage drivers. When new hardware arrives, you just import the drivers to the driver store and regenerate your boot images and them import them into WDS. More information on deployments can be on the [Deploy and Deliver](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/dd641427.aspx) page of the Springboard Series on TechNet.

Hope this Helps,
(signature for disclosure)
David
Windows Outreach Team - IT Pro

Comment: Does WDS in Server 2003 has this feature?

Comment: @gedO MDT is a free download, use the link in my above post. You can install it on the server. Or, you can install it on a workstation and use the WDS deployment share. Here are two short videos to demonstrate how to setup MDT. [Deployment Workbench in Microsoft Deployment Toolkit 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee529974) and [Part 1: Building the Deployment Environment[(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee410767). These will give you an idea of how easy MDT can be to use. Also, MDT can be used as a stand-alone deployment solution (wihtout the server).